# Why can't I download the georeferencing plugin for QGIS 1.7.4?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, download

I used the georeferencing plugin with QGIS 1.6 and now that I've upgraded to 1.7.4 I'd like to do it again. But when I search for the georeferencer plugin, it's not available! Am I doing something wrong?... I also seems that there's no georeferencing option included with version 1.7.4.

Comment: latetest stable production-version is 1.8

Answer (score 6):

The Georeferencer plugin is included as a default plugin.  To activate, in the menu, click `Plugins > Manage Plugins`.  Put a check mark before the `Georeferencer` to activate.